# Problem with IIS rewrite non-www to www and https

Tags: redirect, iis

I've been trying for a few hours now to set up a non-www to www redirect on IIS 8.5 and am failing miserably. I am able to get the home page to force www but all other pages fail. I'm not really an IIS user so this is the first time I have had to do this. So far I have the following:

```
<rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.co.uk$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.co.uk/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

I have also tried the below rule from [OStraining](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/non-www-to-www/) without any luck.

```
<rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.co.uk$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.co.uk/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Can any one assist or shed any light on this?

Comment: If you look at the configuration.php file in the Joomla folder, what value do you have for Livesite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of messing about with the web.config file I had a look around for a plugin that could force the redirect for me. This would not be my normal route, but as an IIS novice (as well as being completely baffled why a large corporation would choose to host Joomla on a windows server) I found the plugin below.

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/www-redirect/

Again, I would never normally go down this route, but without another option, the plugin did the job. Hopefully this may help others in the future (as a last resort I hope).

Regards
D